# What is a connection between ARM and Android?

Tags: android

What is a connection between ARM and Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARM is an instruction set architecture (ISA) -- or more accurately, a family of them -- used for certain CPUs, in the same way that many desktop computers use the x86/amd64 ISAs. The ISA defines the "language" the CPU speaks: what the instructions are, what registers are available, data types, etc.

It happens that ARM processors are popular on mobile devices right now. However, the Android OS is portable, and can run on many different processors, including x86 and MIPS.

Android applications are compiled into bytecode to run on the Dalvik VM, so those are portable across processors as well. (As long as the apps aren't using the NDK to include native code.) This means that, as an app developer, you don't really need to worry about most of this. Your apps should "just run".

More reading:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)